# Play youtube videos in VideoView Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, youtube-data-api, android-videoview

I searched a lot to get stream urls for Youtube videos, but none of them works. Has Youtube removed the support for streaming videos in android videoview?

Code Sample:

```
public String getYoutubeUriForVideoId(String videoId) {
        String url = "";
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "Input video id: "+videoId);
                String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_INFORMATION_URL = 
                        "http://m.youtube.com/watch?ajax=1&layout=mobile&tsp=1&utcoffset=330&v="+videoId; 

                String USER_AGENT ="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-gb; GT-I9003 Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
                Log.e(TAG, "Url: "+YOUTUBE_VIDEO_INFORMATION_URL);
                HttpClient lClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet lGetMethod = new HttpGet(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_INFORMATION_URL);
                // setting the header as to get the high quality video url 
                lGetMethod.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                HttpResponse lResp = lClient.execute(lGetMethod);

                if(lResp == null)
                    return null;
                String lInfoStr = EntityUtils.toString(lResp.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                Log.e(TAG, "Response: "+lInfoStr);
                JSONObject videoInfoJson = new JSONObject(lInfoStr.substring(4,lInfoStr.length()));
                JSONObject content = (JSONObject) videoInfoJson.get("content");
                JSONObject video = (JSONObject) content.get("video");
                JSONArray fmt_stream_map = video.getJSONArray("fmt_stream_map"); 
                url = fmt_stream_map.getJSONObject(0).getString("url");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Youtube stream url: "+url);
            return url;
    }
```

Comment: what you try for that? can you post a piece of code?

Comment: can you start development from your side?? please google first then come for solution.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the sample code please check

Answer (score 0):

you should use  [YouTubeAndroidApi](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for playing YouTube videos for android, it very easiest way.

Here is the example [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but youtube plyer does not allow to capture screenshots from video by coding, thats why i need to switch to videoview